# How to have devise confirmable, run specs, and not blow up SendGrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sendgrid

I just learned the hard way the quickest way to get your account blocked on SendGrid by regularly running a bunch of specs on users that have `Devise#confirmable` on the `User` model.

Is there a preferred method to avoid this problem in the future?

**I just updated my `User Factory` to have setting of `confirmed_at = Time.now`.  Want to make sure I actually fixed the problem and if there is a better way.**

> Woopsee-daisies...
>   [image]

Here's my factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@factory.com" }

  factory :user, aliases: [:author, :commenter] do
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name Faker::Name.last_name
    confirmed_at Time.now
    email
    title 'This is a title'
    password 'password'
    access_code ENV['access_code_secret']
  end
end
```

Here's my db/seeds.rb

```
# Create users
15.times do
  users << User.create!(
    first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
    last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    confirmed_at: Time.now,
    title: Faker::Hipster.sentence,
    bio: Faker::Hipster.paragraph,
    password: Faker::Internet.password(8),
    access_code: ENV['access_code_secret']
  )
end

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Most most common way would be to configure in your `config/environments/test.rb` to not send emails at all when running tests:

```
# Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
# The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

Instead of sending real email Rails would add the emails to an array named `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` while running your tests. That allows you to still write test like:

```
expect { create(:user) }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries }.by(1)
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to equal('foo@example.tld')
```

Comment: Hmmm, I already have that configured at `config/environments/test.rb`.  I'm thinking that the issue was from my `seed` data.  Possible to avoid `ActionMailer` from that end?